# How to add a shortcut for "Launch the selected target in terminal window" button?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use Visual Studio Code and the CMake extension (twxs.cmake). The extension integrates CMake to vscode. There is a button which allows us to run a target in terminal window. It looks like a play button. [image: Like this].
My question is, how can I add a keyboard shortcut for this button? I cannot find the action name so I cannot link it. I wish to use keyboard shortcut instead of clicking that button every time.

I tried googling the action name of this button so I could bind it with any keyboard shortcut, but I couldn't find anything.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Shift+F5** appears to do the same thing as clicking that button.

I found the following [here](https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/debugging.html#running-targets-without-a-debugger):

> ### Running Targets Without a Debugger
>
> Sometimes one will want to just run a target and see its output. This
> can be done with the CMake: Execute the current target without a
> debugger command, or the associated keybinding (the default is
> Shift+F5).
>
> The output of the target will be shown in an integrated terminal.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for! Really appreciate it man...